# Upload files to an enterprise Box.com account without exposing individual credentials

Tags: box-api

I'd like to write an automatic script that will produce a file and upload it to my company's Box account. How can I do this without storing my individual user details (login/password) in my script or on the system that runs the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box has a feature that allows you to upload files to a folder via an email attachment.  You simply select the folder for which you'd like to enable email uploads, and then set the permissions and options for it.  It's neat!

[image: Select the folder for which to enable email uploads]

[image: Configure upload permissions.]

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! Now for the bonus round -- is there a way to get this file without exposing Box credentials? My use case is an ongoing daily report -- ideally the script could retrieve the existing document, append its new data, and upload the new version.

Comment: Yeah -- upload the initial document to the email-enabled folder via the Box web interface.  Then right-click the file and select `Share` -> `Get link to file`.  You should be able to download the file via that link and email it back.  To the best of my knowledge the link and email address won't change.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the "Overwrite same-name files when uploading by email or widget" on my folder properties screen, though ideally it would be checked.

Comment: Might be worth inquiring about.  In the meantime you could date stamp the report, perhaps?

Comment: I'm just an editor. The owner of the folder saw it and checked it. Thanks!

Comment: Just checking in -- do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: Thanks for the followup. We got it working as you described, except we decided to not bother with the script redownloading the data from  Box.

Comment: Hey Steven, I don't mean to be gauche, but if everything's working for you would you mind accepting the answer?  I'd really appreciate it. :)